# High precision floating point numbers in Swift

Tags: swift

How do I handle floating point issue in Swift if Double's precission is not enough? Is there an analog of Java's BigDecimal?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/   is not arbitrary precision but might be enough precision for your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift's `Float80` is higher-precision (but not arbitrarily large).

http://swiftdoc.org/v2.0/type/Float80/